# Finding total distance moved with for loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the overall distance moved by a worker and my `df` looks something  like

```
Name    x    y 
John    12  34
John    15  31
John    8   38
John    20  14
```

I've tried using the `dist(rbind())` function, but the result given is not correct. It just gives the result of `sqrt((row1)^2+(row2)^2+(row3)^2+(row4)^2)`, which I don't think is correct.

So I'm trying to use `for` loop to do this, so that dist between row 1 and 2 , 2 and 3, and so on is calculated separately and summed up later. How would I do this?

My code currently looks like:

```
for(i in nrow(df)){
  n <- dist(rbind(df$x,df$y))
}
```

and this just gives me the wrong single result mentioned above, and not a list of individual distances for each 1-2 row/s.

My expected output would be like:

```
4.2426
9.8995
26.8328
```

and I can sum them up later by I guess running:

```
sum(n)
```

right?

Comment: pls share your expected output!

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli added my expected outcome. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You are not using `i` anywhere in the loop. Probably , you are trying to do , `n[i] <- dist(rbind(df$x[i],df$y[i]))`. Currently, `n` is holding only one value at any given time and probably, the entire thing can be replaced without a loop. I am not sure though, as it is not clear to me.

Comment: what distance calculation are you performing?

Comment: @Wimpel Euclidean distance. I should have mentioned it earlier sorry. So I could just use sqrt((x[1]-x[2])^2+(y[1]-y[2])^2) kind of formula, but I don't know how to do a loop for that. Any help for this please?

Comment: @RonakShah You are right, it's just that I have no idea how to apply for loop in my case. Every example I've seen seem to follow for(i in ___).... code, so I just tried to mimic it. How should I change this?

Comment: Are you sure the first distance value is 2.2426 and not 4.2426?

Comment: @Rage My bad, it is 4.2426. I'll edit it. Thank you

Comment: @Robo No problem. Please do click on the tick mark below the answer to accept. Thanks

Comment: `m <- as.matrix(dist(df[ , 2:3]))`; `m[row(m) - col(m) == 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame("Name" = rep(x = "John",times = 4),"x" = c(12,15,8,20),"y" = c(34,31,38,14))

#> df
#  Name  x  y
#1 John 12 34
#2 John 15 31
#3 John  8 38
#4 John 20 14

n<-numeric()
for(i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)){
  n[i] <- dist(rbind(df[i,-1],df[(i + 1),-1]))
}
print(n)

#[1]  4.242641  9.899495 26.832816

sum(n)

#[1] 40.97495
```

Comment: This code says that there's no object called 'i'. What have I done wrong? Also, how does R know if x or y column is used? Would you be able to explain the code please? I'm quite new to coding & R.

Comment: Actually, it does give me the same result, when I made the data frame following your code. Before, I just used another given dataset. So, how can I mimic this if I was to use an already made-up dataset with 8000+ rows? I cant write c(8000 numbers) for both x and y. It gives me an error same as above if I use the already-made dataset.

Comment: I have removed the first column with the name when I mentioned (-1) here : `df[i,-1],df[(i + 1),-1]`. You can similarly remove any extra columns and just retain the x and y columns.

Answer (score 1):

no loops required

### dplyr

A dplyr/tidyverse approach that also can covers multiple names (since the existence of a 'name'-column indicates multiple workers).

```
df <- data.frame( Name = c("John","John","John","John"),
                  x = c(12,15,8,20),
                  y = c(34,31,38,14),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  #group by name (just in case there are multiple workers in the DF)
  #you can remove this line if there is only 1 worker
  group_by( Name ) %>%
  #get the previous x and y value
  mutate( x_prev = lag( x ), y_prev = lag( y ) ) %>%
  #filter out rows without previous x value
  filter( !is.na( x_prev ) ) %>%
  #calculate the distance
  mutate( distance = sqrt( abs (x - x_prev )^2 + abs( y - y_prev )^2 ) ) %>%
  #summarise to get the total distance
  summarise( total_distance = sum( distance ) )

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     Name  total_distance
#     <chr>          <dbl>
#   1 John            41.0
```

### base R

```
#create a matrix of x and y, calculate the distance and create a matrix from the results
M <- as.matrix( dist( matrix( c( df$x, df$y ), ncol = 2 ) ) )
M
#           1         2         3        4
# 1  0.000000  4.242641  5.656854 21.54066
# 2  4.242641  0.000000  9.899495 17.72005
# 3  5.656854  9.899495  0.000000 26.83282
# 4 21.540659 17.720045 26.832816  0.00000
#get the first off diagonal of the matrix (row = column+1)
M[row(M) == col(M) + 1]
#[1]  4.242641  9.899495 26.832816
#sum the first off diagonal
sum( M[row(M) == col(M) + 1] )
#[1] 40.97495
```

Comment: Yes, there are multiple workers, but I already created a subset for each workers so that each workers have their own individual data frame. So I guess I can start from mutate() section? Also knowing that there aren't any NA values, do I still have to use the filter code? Thank you for the reply and for future response.

Comment: @Robo the NA-filtering is because you cannot calculate the distance for the first row, since the distance travelled is based in the current and the previous values of x and y.  For `n` lines, you will always get `n-1` calculated ditances. Try commenting out lines in the code to see the results up until that point.   In this solution, you do not have to create an individual subset for each worker; you can work on the combined df, and group per worker.

Comment: @Robo added a base solution

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can call the `dist` on each consecutive pair of rows, then `cumsum` the adjacent distances to get your results by Name.

```
df <- read.table(text="Name    x    y 
John    12  34
John    15  31
John    8   38
John    20  14
Mark    11  13
Mark    16  18", header=TRUE)

by(df, df$Name, function(mat) {
    idx <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
    cumsum(mapply(function(i,j) dist(mat[c(i,j), c("x","y")]), 
        head(idx, -1), tail(idx, -1)))
})
```

Alternatively, the below just calculate the whole distance matrix and extract the first off-diagonal

```
by(df, df$Name, function(mat) {
    idx <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
    cumsum(
        as.matrix(dist(mat[,c("x","y")]))[cbind(head(idx, -1), tail(idx, -1))])
})
```

Comment: I've never seen most of the functions you've just suggested here. Thank you for the new information! I'll give it a try soon